# 127.0.0.1 - Meterpreter session 2 closed. Reason: Died

Tags: penetration-test, metasploit

I am new at metasploit and am trying to pentest an Android 5.1 device, so I setup for a stageFright attack  but am having this issue: the 'meterpreter session closed' immediately, and the ngrok reconnects itself.
My question is: how to know if the exploit failed to attack the system? What about 'Meterpreter session 2 closed.  Reason: Died'? Is the problem from the exploit itself or from the ngrok? Any idea how to solve this?
Here is a screenshot:

[image]